# Delay between call and wake-up-to-run of Azure Func app via Http/Blog Triggers/other Triggers with Consumption and Premium Plans

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to know the delay in seconds between a call and the wake-up-to-run of an Azure Func app via `Http/Blog Triggers/other Triggers` with `Consumption` and `Premium` Plans, in the case where it has **not** been called for a long time.

I cannot find the doc from MS below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/

Answer (score 0):

There is some delay in the Starting of Function Running based on the hosting plans like Consumption, App Service plan (dedicated) and Premium because of concept of pre-warmed instances.

Observe the duration of function executions in Application Insights associated with the Function Apps > Performance:

[image]

Observe the duration of function executions in invocation logs in both the hosting plan function apps:
[image]

You can also use the Transaction Search for end-to-end results when host has started and stopped, any errors/warnings between that duration.
If the function is running, you can observe its delay in the Function invocations and in Live Metrics:
[image]